# Error: system event handler not allowed in test module

Tags: capl, canalyzer, canoe

When I run my Script I get the following error,

> Compiling file 'ZTS_Zero_To_Sixty_Analysis.can'
>   Error 1176 at (54,1): System event handler not allowed in test module or test units.
>   Error 1176 at (290,1): System event handler not allowed in test module or test units.

These line are right at my "on start" and "stopmeasurement". However, when I get a program node in `CAnnalyser`, include these scripts and compile them in `Canalyzer`, it does not give me an error.

So I just ignore these errors appearing in CAPL Compiler since they do not impede the running of the scripts, but I would still like to know why CAPL Compiler throws these errors.

Why are these errors thrown?

Comment: Thanks Tiny Giant for editing. I am new to this website. Sorry for pain.

Comment: I don't understand why this post has negative 4 points. This is a legit error .

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that in a test environment, you can not use System event handler. Tests are made to organize and make a modular version of a CAPL script to ensure that a test environment is easily managed.

So in short :

**Simulation node** : Event-based, is used as a sandbox for test nodes.

**Test node** : Modular, has a beginning and an end within the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too this morning. That because your file .can doesn't link any ECU from your simulation. To fix this you have to go in CANoe -> View -> Simulation Setup and there right click on the bus and "Insert Network Node". When you click on this new Node CANoe will open a CAPL editor where you have your new file .can which are now link to a ECU(Node). 
Now you can use on start and StopMeasurement :)